# Gm+6 Chord notation

Tags: notation, chords, chord-theory

I've seen a chord notated as Gm+6 — is that supposed to be a Gm with a 6th so G B D# E ? it sounds really off and unrelated to the song... What is this notation?

context: https://imgur.com/a/DcmtYJC

Comment: Please post an image of the symbol with some of the surrounding context.

Comment: This is not a standard notation. Maybe it could be guessed from the context. It could be either some less notation, or a typo. In particular, as Tim points out, G B D# E would likely be notated as Em(maj7)/G.

Comment: The updates are very helpful; however, it's now clear that the notation is non-standard — both the chord notation and the transliteration of the lyrics. If possible, please add the name of the source so that the original can be looked up.

Answer (score 2):

The latest picture indicates that this is a Gm+6 chord.

Since there is a Gm6/4 chord earlier in the excerpt, I am forced to assume that the "+6" means "add6" and the resulting chord is therefore G-B♭-D-E.

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing such notation before, but the explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This just MIGHT be an attempt to apply chord symbols to 'classical' harmony.  There is a chord called an  Augmented 6th.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_sixth_chord

An Augmented 6th rooted on G would be (or rather COULD be, there are three flavours of the Aug6 chord) G, B, D, E♯, and would typically act as a pre-dominant to something rooted on F♯.

But I suspect it's a mis-named 'G(add6)' or just 'G6'.  Can we see some context?

LATER And now we have some context:
We're in D minor.  It precedes an A7.   Almost certainly an attempt to convey 'Gm plus the 6th'.   And probably really implies 'Em7♭5'.

Comment: How would this be different than a Gm7? (my bad, what's written is a Gm+6, I made an edit, and added a context picture)

Answer (score 0):

First I’d like to point out that in decades of playing and reading music I have never encountered this specific symbol so it is probably an error or a symbol created by someone that doesn’t quite know how to spell chords. Where have you seen this chord symbol? Adding some context (showing the entire page or at least surrounding bars) would be helpful in figuring out exactly what it is.

Assuming this was intentional there are two possibilities, both of which should be written differently for clarity.

The first is a G with an augmented 6th. That is G-B-D-E#. If this is what is desired then it should be written like this; G(+6) or G(add +6). This chord however is enharmonically a G7 so the only reason for writing it the other way is for some theoretical reason, for example showing some type of voice leading: G(b6)-G6-G(+6).

The other option is an augmented triad with an added 6th. That would be G-B-D#-E. That would be better described as G+(6) or G+(add 6) to clarify that it is not the 6th that is augmented. It is unusual but if someone wanted a m2 cluster of D# and E this would be the way to write it.

The bottom line is that assuming no error it is a vague symbol as is. The parentheses I added in each example make it clear one way or the other. The surrounding context might give a clue as to what the writer’s intentions are.

Comment: I wonder whether the + is simply someone's attempt at "add," in other words it's not augmented at all, and is just a G chord with an E added.

Comment: @AndyBonner Isn't that just a G6 chord?

Comment: @AndyBonner It’s possible but not correct as you know. I have seen people use + and - in place of # and b, for example: C7(+9) or C7(-9) but not for adding a note to a chord.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace Yup. I wonder whether that's what's intended. Without the context we'll never know.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace it’s possible that the context might also not even reveal what it actually is, thus my answer, if it’s this write it this way, etc. These “I’ve seen” questions are are usually vague to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Just like John, after decades of reading music, this is a first. Probably written by someone who didn't have much of a clue!

With some surrounding bits, or a snippet of the song at that point, it would ease an answer. However, the best guess would be G**add**6, otherwise usually called simply G6. GBDE. Try that, and hear if it fits in that place. There's often confusion with greenhorns between **+** and **add**, but they're different - **+** means augmented, whereas **add** means play this out-of-chord note too.

EDIT: on reflection - even though OP says it doesn't fit - EGBD♯ *does* produce a recognisable, although fleeting chord, Em (maj7), but I doubt that's the one discussed here.

**EDIT** (to allow for OP's edit) Gm+6 will most likely be Gm(add6), more commonly known as Gm6. Never, or rarely written as Gm+6, which gives completely the wrong name. I vtc, as the question itself contains conflicting information - calling it Gm, then spelling it GB.

Answer (score 0):

While there are several different chord label systems the ones you see most often are pretty consistent and the most common chords used in songs will be fairly obvious to read in those different systems.

Usually you encounter chords that are either diatonic, common altered chords, or "add" or "sus" chords.

The confusion here is "+" usually being used to indicate an "augmented" chord (where the *fifth* of the chord is the augmented chord tone) or whether "+" was meant to mean "add" (mostly for "add2", "add9", or "add6" where all those intervals added are conventionally *major*.)

So, is it supposed to be a `G` augmented triad with an (assumed major) sixth added, or a `G` major triad with an "add6?"

`G` augmented triad with major sixth is `G B D# E` a chord that is neither diatonic nor a common altered chord. If you wanted to write that more clearly, `G+(add6)` would be one way to do it, `Gaug(add6)` is even more emphatic.

`G` is `G B D E` is both diatonic and very, very common. The usual ways to write it are `Gadd6` or just `G6`. Does the chord sound *major*? If so, this is probably the way to go.

As Tim pointed out `G B D# E` could be `Em(maj7)/G`, but *aurally* you would expect that to have a fairly clear *minor* sound.

Do the chords sound unusual? If not, it's more likely the chord is meant to be conventional and it's the writer's way of naming chords that is unusual. You would need an explanation from the writer or a transcription of the song to say more.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have missed that this is a G minor chord (they all suggest using B natural).  Especially given the context and the preceding Gm chord, this is almost certainly a G minor triad, G Bb D, with an added 6th degree, E.  The plus sign is confusing I agree, and Gm6 or Gm(add6) would be clearer.  It could also be written as a half-diminished seventh on E (E G Bb D), which functions as the ii of D minor.

Comment: The answerers didn't miss anything. The question was edited after they answered. The original version asked about a "G+6" chord.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I was wondering how so many people missed that!